# Set up SPF: Facing an error for MX and TXT record

Tags: microsoft-office-365, spf

Our DNS is managed through Microsoft. I need to set up a new record to allow a new website to send email. Here is what I did.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUdBa.png)

Kindly assist. I face the same issue with the TXT record as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Plesk, but I guess you'll need to leave "Mail domain" field empty, as "@.domain.com." doesn't make any sense.

The correct form of the DNS record name would be "domain.com." or "@" (which means "the current DNS zone"). Your Plesk seems to already provide the zone name as suffix so leave it blank.

Also, don't forget to push the last "." (dot) on the Mail Exchange server field. If you omit the last dot (so you put "xxxxx.mail.protection.outlook.com"), it will be translated as "xxxxx.mail.protection.outlook.com.domain.com" and will not work as expected.

The last "." will tell that the hostname is not relative to the current DNS zone.

To check if your DNS configuration is correct, you'll need to use `dig` command (in Unix-like system, Google any alternative for Windows):

```
$ dig MX domain.com @your-domain-nameserver.com
$ dig TXT domain.com @your-domain-nameserver.com
```

Don't forget to replace "your-domain-nameserver.com" by one of your domain's DNS nameserver set at your registrar.

Comment: Thanks @Manoa I will try that and will let you know if it worked.